# Variable get assigned to default at method ends why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have declared two global variable inter ,exter those store value when in if or else condition , but when function ends it value show = 0 (which is initilaized default ) but when i use NSLog in function Else Statement this show correct assigned value = 1or 2 . also tried to use NSString but same issue this assigned to Null ..Code is below have a look :

```
-(void)getFutureAppFrame{


    reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    NSString  *phyIdTemp=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"phyId"];

    NSMutableString *  urlStr=  [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:getFutureApptURL,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"URL"],phyIdTemp, PatientID];
    NSString* encodedUrl = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                            NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSError* error1;
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];



        NSMutableArray *futApptInt = [[dict objectForKey:@"get_appointments"] objectForKey:@"internal"];
        if(futApptInt.count <= 0)
        {
            inter = 1;
        }
        else{
            inter = 2;
        }
        // return;
        futApptInt = [[dict objectForKey:@"get_appointments"] objectForKey:@"external"];
        if(futApptInt.count <= 0)
        {
            exter =1;
        }
        else{
            exter = 2;
        }
        NSLog(@"CheckELSE %d --%d",exter , inter);

    }];
    NSLog(@"CHECKF %d --%d",exter , inter);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of `inter` ,`exter` are not set until the network operation completes which is **after** the `NSLog()` statement because it is outside of the asynchronous block. That is the nature of asynchronous operations,

Comment: what will solution im new to it ..Thanks for Reply

Comment: @iDeepak, you need to wait until asynchronous block get complete, then only you can get a value of exter & inter.

Comment: @pawan thanks for reply , asper i tested added nslog in various point in uIButton to Viewdidload , viewwill appear but no where it assigning value just default always

Comment: could you lead me either i required a new function or i can do it in this function

Comment: @iDeepak You can create a new function which will get called after block completion, there you will get updated value.

Comment: @iDeepak You need to take the time to learn about asynchronous calls, why and how to work with them. here is a lot of information on the Internet starting with Apple documentation, WWDC videos, books and tutorials.